What dependency do I need to get GettextResourceManager?
Here is the C# manual for gettext. It claims:

Prerequisite
—

It also shows usage of a class GNU.Gettext.GettextResourceManager.

In a Mono 6.12.0.200 project on Debian Buster there is no GettextResourceManager.
In a .NET 8.0.303 project on Debian Bookworm there is no GettextResourceManager.

Here is the Debian package view (linked for Buster, but I also checked Bookworm).
It does not seem to contain any viable dependencies for a C# project to provide the class.
Here is the Guix package view for gettext.
There are two Ruby and one Lisp library, but none for C#.
Here is the gettext source.
It contains no .cs files and therefore can presumably provide a native-C binding but no C# class GNU.Gettext.GettextResourceManager. (Or at least all such binding classes I have seen so far have always been written in the target language, never in the source language. This may be a misconception on my part.)
What is the dependency that I have to include?
Where should I have been looking for setup instructions? (Presumably elsewhere in the same manual?)
Here are third-party C# projects that do provide a GNU.Gettext.GettextResourceManager but of course, I'd rather not use one of these if I do not have to. (Does the manual lie?)

Stride.GNU.Gettext nuGet package for .NET 6
arbinada-com/gettext-dotnet .NET reimplementation

